# backbone view why can't I trigger UI event in initialize?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, backbone.js

I am using bootstrap tabs in my html, and backbone for events and models.  I wanted to trigger tab shown event for bootstrap, so that I can handle the event to create another view (sub view).

This is my code:

```
var HeaderView = Backbone.View.extend({
    ...
    events : {
       'shown.bs.tab ul.nav-tabs>li>a': 'onTabShown'
    },
    initialize:function() {
        console.log("Header view initialize executing...");
        this.template =_.template(UserTemplate, this.collection); 
        this.render();
        this.$el.find('div.toolbar ul.nav-tabs>li:first>a').tab('show');
        //$('ul.nav-tabs>li:first>a').tab('show');
    },
    onTabShown: function() {
        console.log('tab shown event!');
    }
    ...
}
```

However, even though initialize code is executing successfully, the tab shown event is not triggering.  For that matter, any UI event raised in the initialize() is not triggering.

This works if I call the event trigger outside of the view module, after creation.

Is it possible that the UI event is not triggered, because the view is not yet fully initialized, since initialize is still executing?  It seems that the work around is to call the trigger of tab shown event from some other code outside of this View.  Is there any better approach or practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not working, because you're not calling the "delegateEvents".
Add this.delegateEvents() to your initialize and it will work.
Now, the reason it's not working as expected, is because you're doing all the work in the initialize method, which is called by the Backbone.View constructor before it delegates the events. It's considered a very bad practice to do anything but initialization in the initialize method of the Backbone.View. Also, save yourself time, and use Marionette...

Comment: OK.  For the second suggestion, Indeed, I am using Marionette in my above app. For brevity, I have not shown those.

Comment: If you're using Marionette, the region's show method will call render, so this is another reason no to call it in initialize(). Put the `tab('show')` in the onRender method.